# Error 400 with YouTube API and C#?

Tags: c#, youtube

I am trying to update the title to a video, with an authorized put in C#:

```
string postUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&access_token=" + this.access_token;
string postData = "id=" + this.videoID +
    "&snippet[title]=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status.Text) +
    "&snippet[categoryId]=20";
byte[] postByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);

request.Method = "PUT";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postByte.Length;
request.Timeout = 15000;

try
{
    Stream putStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    putStream.Write(postByte, 0, postByte.Length);
    putStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

The above code shows the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `snippet.title` and `snippet.categoryId` instead of the current format? From what I can see you have to give a full JSON video object as the body anyway, but they might take form encoded data too and I just can't see it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This particular endpoint needs a `json` responce, instead of a `x-www-form-urlencoded` response.